# How to overcome Fast Search char limitation 2048

Tags: sharepoint, search, facebook-fql

We are using FQL (FAST Query Language) to get data from some search scopes.

In one search scope there are almost 400 path rules which makes my QueryText out of index (limit is 2048).

Since FQL does not support scope directly so we are using the following code:

```
foreach (Scope scope in scopes.GetScopesForSite(null)) {
     scopeLookup += scope.Filter;
}

myQuery.QueryText= scopeLookup;
```

Last line throws an error when text limit exceeds 2048 chars.